# How to find the number of sequences of zeros and ones without "111"

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic

I have a problem:
I have a N (N <= 40). N is a length of sequence of zeroz and ones. How to find the number of sequences of zeros and ones in which there are no three "1" together?

Example:
N = 3, answer = 7

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
```

Comment: Without a specific language to use a reference all I can say is... read down the list and count them :)

Comment: Do you mean programmatically? This sounds like a combinatorics problem

Comment: Yes. It is a problem from the section about dynamic programming. I write on C++.

Comment: I know that if we want to find the number of sequences without "11" our answer will be N + 1 Fibonacci number. May be it will help.

Comment: since you're learning, here's just a hint. think about how to combine answers from smaller n's. why for 11 its fibonacci? get paper and pencil, and think about the patterns you see.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A000073

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using a recursive function :

(PHP code here, but it's really simple)

```
$seq = '';

function tree ($node, $flag, $seq)
{
if ($flag == 3) { return 0; }

if ($node == 0) { echo $seq, ' '; return 0;}

$seq1 = $seq.'1';
$seq2 = $seq.'0';

tree($node-1, $flag+1, $seq1);
tree($node-1, 0, $seq2);

}

tree(8, 0, $seq);
```

I use a tree to go through all the possible sequences, and a flag to check how many 1 in a row.

If there is two 1 in a row, then the flag reaches 3, and the function is stopped for this branch.

If we reach a leaf of the tree (ie. $node = 0), then the sequence is displayed, and the function ends.

Else, the function explores the two sub-trees starting from the current node.

```
void tree ( int node, int flag, std::string seq)
{
    std::string seq1 = seq;        
    std::string seq2 = seq;

    if(flag ==3) { return; }
    if(node ==0) { printf("%s\n",seq.c_str()); return;}

    seq1 += '1';
    seq2 += '0';

    tree(node-1, flag+1, seq1);
    tree(node-1, 0, seq2);

}
```

Comment: Heheheh, +1. PHP answer to C++ 'no code' question - nice approach.

Comment: @MartinJames alright, you got me, I used the language I'm most comfortable with ! I'll adapt the code to C++ :)

Comment: @MartinJames Done ! I tried it, it works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a grammar for the (non-empty) strings of this language. It's designed so that each string appears exactly once.

```
S := 0 | 1 | 11 | 10 | 110 | 0S | 10S | 110S
```

Let a_i be the total number of strings of length i in S.

First, look at the number of strings of length 1 on both sides of the grammar rule. There's a_1 in S by definition which deals with the left-hand-side.

```
a_1 = 2
```

For a_2, on the right-hand-side we immediately get two strings of length 2 (11 and 10), plus another two from the 0S rule (00 and 01). This gives us:

```
a_2 = 2 + a_1 = 4
```

Similarly, for a_3, we get:

```
a_3 = 1 + a_2 + a_1 = 7
```

(So far so good, we've got the right solution 7 for the case where the strings are length three).

For i > 3, consider the number of strings of length i on both sides.

```
a_i = a_{i-1} + a_{i-2} + a_{i-3}
```

Now we've got a recurrence we can use. A quick check for a_4...

```
a_4 = a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = 2 + 4 + 7 = 13.
```

There's 16 strings of length 4 and three containing 111: 1110, 0111, 1111. So 13 looks right!

Here's some code in Python for the general case, using this recurrence.

```
def strings_without_111(n):
    if n == 0: return 1
    a = [2, 4, 7]
    for _ in xrange(n - 1):
        a = [a[1], a[2], a[0] + a[1] + a[2]]
    return a[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a dp problem. I will explain the solution in a way so that it is easy to modify it to count the number of sequences having no sequence a<sub>0</sub>a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub> in them(where a<sub>i</sub> is arbitrary binary value).

I will use 4 helper variables each counting the sequence up to a given length that are valid and end with 00, 01, 10, and 11 respectively. Name those c00, c01, c10, c11. It is pretty obvious that for length N = 2, those numbers are all 1:

```
int c00 = 1;
int c01 = 1;
int c10 = 1;
int c11 = 1;
```

Now assuming we have counted the sequences up to a given length `k` we count the sequences in the four groups for length `k + 1` in the following manner:

```
int new_c00 = c10 + c00; 
int new_c01 = c10 + c00;
int new_c10 = c01 + c11;
int new_c11 = c01;
```

The logic above is pretty simple - if we append a `0` to either a sequence of length `k` ending at `0 0` or ending at `1 0` we end up with a new sequence of length `k + 1` and ending with `0 0` and so on for the other equations above.

Note that c11 is not added to the number of sequences ending with `1 1` and with length `k + 1`. That is because if we append 1 to a sequence ending with `1 1` we will end up with an invalid sequence( ending at `1 1 1`).

Here is a complete solution for your case:

```
int c00 = 1;
int c01 = 1;
int c10 = 1;
int c11 = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; ++i) {
  int new_c00 = c10 + c00; 
  int new_c01 = c10 + c00;
  int new_c10 = c01 + c11;
  int new_c11 = c01;
  c00 = new_c00;
  c01 = new_c01;
  c10 = new_c10;
  c11 = new_c11;
}
// total valid sequences of length n
int result = c00 + c01 + c10 + c11; 
cout << result << endl;
```

Also you will have to take special care for the case when N < 2, because the above solution does not handle that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To find a number of all possible sequences for `N` bits are easy. It is `2^N`.

To find all sequences contains `111` a bit harder.

Assume `N=3` then `Count = 1`

```
111
```

Assume `N=4` then `Count = 3`

```
0111
1110
1111
```

Assume `N=5` then `Count = 8`

```
11100
11101
11110
11111
01110
01111
00111
10111
```

If you write simple simulation program it yields `1 3 8 20 47 107 ...`

Subtract `2^n - count(n)` = `2 4 7 13 24 44 81 149...`

Google it and it gives [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000073) sequence, known as tribonacci numbers. Solved by simple recurrent equation:

`a(n) = a(n - 1) + a(n - 2) + a(n - 3)`